# R: "plotmath" produces extra white space when using Computer Modern fonts

Tags: r, fonts, plotmath

More specifically, the "juxtapose" feature [i.e. "*" or "paste"] produces extra white space when using the "CM Roman" font family. With other families [e.g. "CenturySch"] it works fine. An issue of R [using 3.0.2]? Or invalid font source file?

A MWE [note unwanted white space after the first "sin"]:

```
library(extrafont)
postscript(file="example.eps",heigh=5,width=5,fonts=c("CM Roman","CenturySch"))
plot(2,type="n")
text(1,2,  expression( "sin"*(e^{-italic(t)} )),family="CM Roman",  cex=2 )
text(1,1.5,expression( "sin"*(e^{-italic(t)} )),family="CenturySch",cex=2 )
dev.off()
```

unwanted white space after the first "sin":

[image]

Thank you for any response.

M.

Comment: Why don't you use `sin(e^{-italic(t)})`?

Comment: Roland, it simply produces "Error: unexpected ',' in ..."

Comment: There is no `,` in this expression.